# Get Profit by last Purchase's price with Sale's Price based on Product Id, sold on Date

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

I'm trying to optimize my current query which is calculating profit based on last purchase's net amount, depending upon product's selling date and quantity in sale's table. Currently, it's consuming too much memory and time.

Spacking is an item's selling unit. For Example, if spacking of x product is 10 which means it could be sold in 10 pieces, or let's say a box contains 10 items, but we count it as 1 box, but we also sell it in pieces, so spacking would be 10 for that item. Then net amount of that item per unit would be net_amount/spacking.

In the nested query, I'm calculating the price of a unit by ((total amount of that product id /quantity))/spacking and multiplying it with the current selling quantity, then subtracting it from the total selling price which will give me a profit of that product.

Product

| pcode (varchar(10)) | product_name (varchar(50)) | spacking (int) | Price (double) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1343 | Chocolates Box | 10 | $20 |
| 1344 | Panadol Strip | 1 | $10 |
| 1345 | Neurobion Inj | 5 | $2 |

Purchase

| Product_code (FKey - Product's pcode) | date (date) | Full_item (int) | Pieces (int) | Bonus (int) | Discount (double) | Net Amount/Total Amount (double) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1343 | 23-03-2021 | 10 | 0 | 2 | 2% | $130 |
| 1343 | 22-03-2021 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 2% | $130 |
| 1344 | 22-03-2021 | 5 | 0 |  | 5% | $15 |
| 1344 | 1-03-2021 | 5 | 0 |  | 5% | $10 |
| 1343 | 22-03-2021 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 2% | $130 |
| 1343 | 21-03-2021 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 2% | $130 |

Sale

| Product_code (FKey - Product's pcode) | date (date) | Full_item (int) | Pieces (int) | Bonus (int) | Discount (double) | Net Amount/Total Amount (double) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1343 | 23-03-2021 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0% | $40 |
| 1344 | 22-03-2021 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0% | $10 |
| 1343 | 21-03-2021 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0% | $20 |
| 1343 | 22-03-2021 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 0% | $18 |
| 1343 | 21-03-2021 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0% | $20 |

In sale, I'm adding all the sale's transaction for each item that was purchased, each day it may have a different purchased price, to get the profit, we have to subtract the selling price from the latest purchasing price of an item. So date also plays a role here to extract the exact profit, as the sale of an item can be from different dates.

Hence, I wrote a query below which fetches all the records of sale along with its profit on each product.

for a single day, 461 rows, Query took 4.2298 seconds. for multiple days' record, it takes a long time to process.

```
select
   product.product_name,
   product.pcode,
   product.spacking,
   (
   select
      round(sale.net_amount - ( (round((p.net_amount / (p.full_item + p.bonus_full)), 2) / product.spacking)* ((sale.full_item + sale.bonus_full)* product.spacking ) + (round((p.net_amount / (p.full_item + p.bonus_full)), 2) / product.spacking)* (sale.pieces)), 2
   ) 
   from
      purchase p 
   where
      p.invoice_date <= sale.invoice_date 
      and sale.product_code = p.product_code 
   order by
      p.invoice_date desc LIMIT 1)) as pnet_amount,
      DATE_FORMAT(sale.invoice_date, '%M %d %Y') as date,
      sale.invoice_number,
      sale.full_item,
      sale.pieces,
      sale.bonus_full_item,
      sale.price,
      sale.discount,
      sale.net_amount 
   from
      sale 
      join
         product 
         on product.pcode = sale.product_code 
      join
         customer 
         on customer.ccode = sale.customer_code 
   where
      sale.invoice_date BETWEEN '2021-03-14' and '2021-03-16' 
   order by
      sale.invoice_date desc
```

Comment: How much memory and time? Where are the schemas of all tables invovled and the current execution plan?

Comment: You should post the _schemas_ of tables, i.e. including all columns' types and all indexes defined, so readers can make informed judgements about what might be slowing you down.

Comment: I've just added it, but it doesn't formate it in tabular form but I hope it's understandable. Please let me know if you need any further information, I've too many rows to process with this query and nested query runs for each row which takes hug time.

Comment: There's not enough Spacking in this world

Comment: We still can't see column types or indexes of the table, nor any execution plan, leaving readers to speculate instead of being able to reason about your data with proper context.

Comment: I've added all the information, please let me know if any other clarification is required there. Apologies for not responding timely, as this is my first post here.